# can not load exported blender gltf to qt 3d mesh

Tags: qt, 3d, qml, blender, gltf

my problem is i can not load gltf mesh from blender into qt 3d mesh file .
the start arrange in blender that contain a cube ,camera and one light exported to gltf file formate (separate bin and gltf)

```
{
"asset" : {
    "generator" : "Khronos glTF Blender I/O v1.0.5",
    "version" : "2.0"
},
"scene" : 0,
"scenes" : [
    {
        "name" : "Scene",
        "nodes" : [
            0,
            1,
            3
        ]
    }
],
"nodes" : [
    {
        "mesh" : 0,
        "name" : "Cube"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Light",
        "rotation" : [
            0.16907575726509094,
            0.7558803558349609,
            -0.27217137813568115,
            0.570947527885437
        ],
        "translation" : [
            4.076245307922363,
            5.903861999511719,
            -1.0054539442062378
        ]
    },
    {
        "camera" : 0,
        "name" : "Camera_Orientation",
        "rotation" : [
            -0.7071067690849304,
            0,
            0,
            0.7071067690849304
        ]
    },
    {
        "children" : [
            2
        ],
        "name" : "Camera",
        "rotation" : [
            0.483536034822464,
            0.33687159419059753,
            -0.20870360732078552,
            0.7804827094078064
        ],
        "translation" : [
            7.358891487121582,
            4.958309173583984,
            6.925790786743164
        ]
    }
],
"cameras" : [
    {
        "name" : "Camera",
        "perspective" : {
            "yfov" : 0.39959652046304894,
            "zfar" : 100,
            "znear" : 0.10000000149011612
        },
        "type" : "perspective"
    }
],
"materials" : [
    {
        "doubleSided" : true,
        "name" : "Material",
        "pbrMetallicRoughness" : {
            "baseColorFactor" : [
                0.800000011920929,
                0.800000011920929,
                0.800000011920929,
                1
            ],
            "metallicFactor" : 0,
            "roughnessFactor" : 0.4000000059604645
        }
    }
],
"meshes" : [
    {
        "name" : "Cube",
        "primitives" : [
            {
                "attributes" : {
                    "POSITION" : 0,
                    "NORMAL" : 1,
                    "TEXCOORD_0" : 2
                },
                "indices" : 3,
                "material" : 0
            }
        ]
    }
],
"accessors" : [
    {
        "bufferView" : 0,
        "componentType" : 5126,
        "count" : 24,
        "max" : [
            1,
            1,
            1
        ],
        "min" : [
            -1,
            -1,
            -1
        ],
        "type" : "VEC3"
    },
    {
        "bufferView" : 1,
        "componentType" : 5126,
        "count" : 24,
        "type" : "VEC3"
    },
    {
        "bufferView" : 2,
        "componentType" : 5126,
        "count" : 24,
        "type" : "VEC2"
    },
    {
        "bufferView" : 3,
        "componentType" : 5123,
        "count" : 36,
        "type" : "SCALAR"
    }
],
"bufferViews" : [
    {
        "buffer" : 0,
        "byteLength" : 288,
        "byteOffset" : 0
    },
    {
        "buffer" : 0,
        "byteLength" : 288,
        "byteOffset" : 288
    },
    {
        "buffer" : 0,
        "byteLength" : 192,
        "byteOffset" : 576
    },
    {
        "buffer" : 0,
        "byteLength" : 72,
        "byteOffset" : 768
    }
],
"buffers" : [
    {
        "byteLength" : 840,
        "uri" : "cube.bin"
    }
]}
```

and replace our gltf file into bouncing-ball kdab example :
[bouncing-ball Example](https://github.com/KDAB/qt3d-examples/tree/master/bouncing-ball)

and test many many export file without camera and light or other mesh file.

just default gltf that kdab write for ball.gltf work and my exported gltf not work.
where is my fault ?
my export routine wrong ?
this is kdab ball.gltf :

```
{
"accessors" : [
    {
        "bufferView" : 0, 
        "componentType" : 5123, 
        "count" : 5136, 
        "max" : [
            1338
        ], 
        "min" : [
            0
        ], 
        "type" : "SCALAR"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 1, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 1339, 
        "max" : [
            0.5096009969711304, 
            0.5091260075569153, 
            0.5093899965286255
        ], 
        "min" : [
            -0.5096009969711304, 
            -0.5091260075569153, 
            -0.5093899965286255
        ], 
        "type" : "VEC3"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 2, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 1339, 
        "max" : [
            0.9904782176017761, 
            0.9841609001159668, 
            0.9891659021377563
        ], 
        "min" : [
            -0.9904782176017761, 
            -0.9841609001159668, 
            -0.9891964197158813
        ], 
        "type" : "VEC3"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 3, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 1339, 
        "max" : [
            1.0, 
            0.865885317325592, 
            0.9904893040657043, 
            1.0
        ], 
        "min" : [
            -0.9978849291801453, 
            -0.865885317325592, 
            -0.9904893040657043, 
            1.0
        ], 
        "type" : "VEC4"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 4, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 1339, 
        "max" : [
            0.39070799946784973, 
            1.0
        ], 
        "min" : [
            0.0, 
            0.32749998569488525
        ], 
        "type" : "VEC2"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 5, 
        "componentType" : 5123, 
        "count" : 2628, 
        "max" : [
            725
        ], 
        "min" : [
            0
        ], 
        "type" : "SCALAR"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 6, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 726, 
        "max" : [
            0.5073130130767822, 
            0.5070769786834717, 
            0.5071730017662048
        ], 
        "min" : [
            -0.5073130130767822, 
            -0.5070769786834717, 
            -0.507174015045166
        ], 
        "type" : "VEC3"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 7, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 726, 
        "max" : [
            0.9904782176017761, 
            0.9834284782409668, 
            0.9972838759422302
        ], 
        "min" : [
            -0.9904782176017761, 
            -0.9834284782409668, 
            -0.9973143935203552
        ], 
        "type" : "VEC3"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 8, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 726, 
        "max" : [
            1.0, 
            0.7974647879600525, 
            0.9962546229362488, 
            1.0
        ], 
        "min" : [
            -0.9973154067993164, 
            -0.797484815120697, 
            -0.996262788772583, 
            1.0
        ], 
        "type" : "VEC4"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 9, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 726, 
        "max" : [
            0.39070799946784973, 
            0.6489929854869843
        ], 
        "min" : [
            0.1846970021724701, 
            0.32733798027038574
        ], 
        "type" : "VEC2"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 10, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 59, 
        "max" : [
            2.416666666666667
        ], 
        "min" : [
            0.0
        ], 
        "type" : "SCALAR"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 11, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 177, 
        "max" : [
            5.6162285804748535, 
            14.311456680297852, 
            -0.0
        ], 
        "min" : [
            -6.767030715942383, 
            -14.364005088806152, 
            -0.0
        ], 
        "type" : "VEC3"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 12, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 59, 
        "max" : [
            2.416666666666667
        ], 
        "min" : [
            0.0
        ], 
        "type" : "SCALAR"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 13, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 59, 
        "max" : [
            0.0, 
            0.0, 
            0.9993862509727478, 
            1.0
        ], 
        "min" : [
            0.0, 
            0.0, 
            -0.0, 
            -0.9947023987770081
        ], 
        "type" : "VEC4"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 14, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 1, 
        "max" : [
            0.0
        ], 
        "min" : [
            0.0
        ], 
        "type" : "SCALAR"
    }, 
    {
        "bufferView" : 15, 
        "componentType" : 5126, 
        "count" : 3, 
        "max" : [
            1.0, 
            1.0, 
            1.0
        ], 
        "min" : [
            0.0, 
            0.0, 
            0.0
        ], 
        "type" : "VEC3"
    }
], 
"animations" : [
    {
        "channels" : [
            {
                "sampler" : 0, 
                "target" : {
                    "node" : 0, 
                    "path" : "translation"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "sampler" : 1, 
                "target" : {
                    "node" : 0, 
                    "path" : "rotation"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "sampler" : 2, 
                "target" : {
                    "node" : 0, 
                    "path" : "scale"
                }
            }
        ], 
        "samplers" : [
            {
                "input" : 10, 
                "interpolation" : "CUBICSPLINE", 
                "output" : 11
            }, 
            {
                "input" : 12, 
                "interpolation" : "LINEAR", 
                "output" : 13
            }, 
            {
                "input" : 14, 
                "interpolation" : "CUBICSPLINE", 
                "output" : 15
            }
        ]
    }
], 
"asset" : {
    "generator" : "Khronos Blender glTF 2.0 exporter", 
    "version" : "2.0"
}, 
"bufferViews" : [
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 10272, 
        "byteOffset" : 0, 
        "target" : 34963
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 16068, 
        "byteOffset" : 10272, 
        "target" : 34962
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 16068, 
        "byteOffset" : 26340, 
        "target" : 34962
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 21424, 
        "byteOffset" : 42408, 
        "target" : 34962
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 10712, 
        "byteOffset" : 63832, 
        "target" : 34962
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 5256, 
        "byteOffset" : 74544, 
        "target" : 34963
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 8712, 
        "byteOffset" : 79800, 
        "target" : 34962
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 8712, 
        "byteOffset" : 88512, 
        "target" : 34962
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 11616, 
        "byteOffset" : 97224, 
        "target" : 34962
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 5808, 
        "byteOffset" : 108840, 
        "target" : 34962
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 236, 
        "byteOffset" : 114648
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 2124, 
        "byteOffset" : 114884
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 236, 
        "byteOffset" : 117008
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 944, 
        "byteOffset" : 117244
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 4, 
        "byteOffset" : 118188
    }, 
    {
        "buffer" : 0, 
        "byteLength" : 36, 
        "byteOffset" : 118192
    }
], 
"buffers" : [
    {
        "byteLength" : 118228, 
        "uri" : "ball.bin"
    }
], 
"cameras" : [
    {
        "name" : "Camera", 
        "orthographic" : {
            "xmag" : 10.0, 
            "ymag" : 10.0, 
            "zfar" : 100.0, 
            "znear" : 0.10000000149011612
        }, 
        "type" : "orthographic"
    }
], 
"materials" : [
    {
        "alphaMode" : "BLEND", 
        "name" : "Basketball_col_1", 
        "pbrMetallicRoughness" : {
            "baseColorFactor" : [
                0.6399999856948853, 
                0.11156400293111801, 
                0.012199999764561653, 
                1.0
            ], 
            "metallicFactor" : 0.0
        }
    }, 
    {
        "alphaMode" : "BLEND", 
        "name" : "Basketball_col_2", 
        "pbrMetallicRoughness" : {
            "baseColorFactor" : [
                0.012853999622166157, 
                0.0039470000192523, 
                0.0011840000515803695, 
                1.0
            ], 
            "metallicFactor" : 0.0
        }
    }
], 
"meshes" : [
    {
        "name" : "basketball", 
        "primitives" : [
            {
                "attributes" : {
                    "NORMAL" : 2, 
                    "POSITION" : 1, 
                    "TANGENT" : 3, 
                    "TEXCOORD_0" : 4
                }, 
                "indices" : 0, 
                "material" : 0
            }, 
            {
                "attributes" : {
                    "NORMAL" : 7, 
                    "POSITION" : 6, 
                    "TANGENT" : 8, 
                    "TEXCOORD_0" : 9
                }, 
                "indices" : 5, 
                "material" : 1
            }
        ]
    }
], 
"nodes" : [
    {
        "mesh" : 0, 
        "name" : "ball", 
        "translation" : [
            5.6162285804748535, 
            3.6729564666748047, 
            -0.0
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "camera" : 0, 
        "name" : "Correction_Camera", 
        "rotation" : [
            -0.7071067690849304, 
            -0.0, 
            0.0, 
            0.7071067690849304
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "children" : [
            1
        ], 
        "name" : "Camera", 
        "rotation" : [
            0.7071068286895752, 
            0.0, 
            -0.0, 
            0.7071067094802856
        ], 
        "translation" : [
            0.0, 
            2.163846969604492, 
            29.8966064453125
        ]
    }
], 
"scene" : 0, 
"scenes" : [
    {
        "name" : "Scene", 
        "nodes" : [
            0, 
            2
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Please explain what your _can not load_ means? Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt to do that.

Comment: It's not possible to reproduce this problem from the portion of the file attached here. Can you view the file on https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ and https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/? If so, please file a bug on QT 3D. If not, I would suggest filing a bug on the software used to create the file.

Comment: Have you tried with/out the geometry compression? The generator tag shows v1.0.5 which is what shipped with blender v2.81, the current dev is at v1.1.29 Maybe try extracing the gltf addon files from the current [blender addons](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/) and trying that.